# How can i install perl 5.10.1 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I am not able to install Perl 5.10.1 in ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to install it via perlbrew but I am getting some error.

```
perlbrew install perl-5.10.1

apt-get install perlbrew
perlbrew init
perlbrew install perl-5.10.1
perlbrew use perl-5.10.1
```

I have to downgrade the Perl version since I am in need of these for my applications backend

```
*Error Message:
Test Summary Report
-------------------
makefile:850: recipe for target '_test_tty' failed
make[2]: *** [_test_tty] Error 255
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.10.1/perl-5.10.1'
makefile:864: recipe for target '_test' failed
make[1]: *** [_test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.10.1/perl-5.10.1'
makefile:967: recipe for target 'test_harness' failed
make: *** [test_harness] Error 2
##### Brew Failed #####*
```

Comment: Do I need to install forcefully? will it work without any issue?

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 19.04, and also got failed tests. Specifically `op/range.t` is failing. Which OS are you on? According to [this issue](https://github.com/bingos/devel-patchperl/issues/23) for `devel-patchperl`, it is related to `gcc`

Comment: Could you show the failing test (not just the summary)

Answer (score 3):

If you update the `patchperl` component of your `perlbrew` to the latest version, it should work. See [this issue](https://github.com/bingos/devel-patchperl/issues/23) for more information. Try this:

```
$ perlbrew install-patchperl  # <-- install latest version of patchperl
$ perlbrew install perl-5.10.1
```